# Question about assumptions in proof of continuity of $x^2$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, epsilon-delta

When proving that $x^2$ is continuous we usually show that $\lim_{x \to\ a} x^2 = a^2$ for any x.

So we show that for any $\epsilon > 0$, there is a $\delta > 0$ such that $0< | x-a | <\delta$ implies that $|x^2-a^2|<\epsilon$. We have $|x^2-a^2| = (|x+a|)(|x-a|) < \epsilon $. At this point the book I'm reading puts a bound on the $|x-a|$ term. Why does this work? Is it because $|x-a|$ can be as small as possible since continuity is a local property, so x can be as close a as we like?

Comment: It works because you can assume that if $|x-a|$ is bounded, say $|x-a| < c$, then a particular choice $\delta_0$ works. Then in the end you just specify $\delta$ so that $\delta = \min(\delta_0, c)$.

Comment: Right, but why is it okay to assume that $|x-a|$ is bounded? What happens if $|x-a|>c$?

Comment: I'll expand on this in an answer

Comment: @orange_juice $|x-a|$ is bounded because of you initial assumption $0<|x-a|<\delta$, as $\delta$ is a constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intuitively, you have the right idea. For $f(x) = x^2$, the bound $|x-a|<1$ is common. It makes sense; why bother considering $x$ more than a unit away from $a$? We only care about $x$ in the immediate vicinity of $a$. However, we need a formal justification.

Let us only consider $x$ such that $|x-a|<1$. Then we have $|x| < 1 + |a|$ so that $|x-a||x+a| \leq |x-a|(|x| + |a|) < |x-a|(2|a| + 1) < \epsilon$. Thus, *assuming* $|x-a|<1$, we choose

$$\delta_0 = \frac{\epsilon}{2|a| + 1}$$

Now, given that $|x-a|<1$, $|x-a|<\delta_0 \Longrightarrow |x^2 - a^2|< \epsilon$.

Now, you ask, what if $|x-a|>1$. Well, we can avoid this scenario entirely by choosing.

$$\delta = \min\left(\delta_0, 1\right)$$

With such $\delta$, $|x-a|$ satisfies both $|x-a|<1$ and $|x-a|<\delta_0$

Since we have already established that $|x-a| < \delta_0$ and $|x-a|<1$ implies $|x^2 - a^2| < \epsilon$, we are done.